# Hard Query with SqlServer (with When and else)

Tags: sql-server

i have a query but i don't know why it is bad. 
The error is: SQL (4104): Invalid column name 'CUSTOMDATA2' The multi-part identifier "PCO.QUALIFICATIONCODE.code" could not be bound, but i don't uderstand where and why it is bad.

I am very lost with this query :/, some guru of querys can i help me ?. 
Edited query for dont hurt people.
Thank you in advance.

```
SELECT PCO_QUALIFICATIONCODE.CODE,
  CASE
    WHEN (ActividadesActivas.[CUSTOMDATA2] IS NULL)
    THEN
      (SELECT Description
      FROM PCO_QUALIFICATIONCODE BIS
      WHERE SERVICEID = 1
      AND BIS.CODE    = SUBSTRING(CAST(PCO_QUALIFICATIONCODE.CODE AS VARCHAR), 1, 3)
      )
    ELSE ActividadesActivas.[CUSTOMDATA2]
  END CUSTOMDATA2,
  CASE
    WHEN (ActividadesActivas.[CUSTOMDATA3] IS NULL)
    THEN
      CASE
        WHEN (SUBSTRING(CAST(CODE AS VARCHAR), 5, 1) <> '')
        THEN
          (SELECT Description
          FROM PCO_QUALIFICATIONCODE BIS
          WHERE SERVICEID = 1
          AND BIS.CODE    = SUBSTRING(CAST(PCO_QUALIFICATIONCODE.CODE AS VARCHAR), 1, 5)
          )
        WHEN (SUBSTRING(CAST(CODE AS VARCHAR), 4, 1) <> '')
        THEN
          (SELECT Description
          FROM PCO_QUALIFICATIONCODE BIS
          WHERE SERVICEID = 1
          AND BIS.CODE    = SUBSTRING(CAST(PCO_QUALIFICATIONCODE.CODE AS VARCHAR), 1, 4)
          )
        WHEN ActividadesActivas.[CUSTOMDATA3] IS NULL
        OR ActividadesActivas.[CUSTOMDATA3]    = 'NULL'
        THEN ''
        ELSE ActividadesActivas.[CUSTOMDATA3]
      END
    ELSE ActividadesActivas.[CUSTOMDATA3]
  END CUSTOMDATA3,
  Totales.TOTAL
FROM [SQLPR1].[PREP].PCO_QUALIFICATIONCODE
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT [QCODE],
    CASE
      WHEN ((SUBSTRING(CAST(QCODE AS VARCHAR), 1, 3) IS NOT NULL)
      AND (SUBSTRING(CAST(QCODE AS   VARCHAR), 4, 1)  = '')
      AND (SUBSTRING(CAST(QCODE AS   VARCHAR), 5, 1)  = '') )
      THEN
        (SELECT Description
        FROM PCO_QUALIFICATIONCODE
        WHERE SERVICEID = 1
        AND CODE        = SUBSTRING(CAST(QCODE AS VARCHAR), 1, 3)
        )
      WHEN ((SUBSTRING(CAST(QCODE AS VARCHAR), 1, 3) IS NOT NULL)
      AND (SUBSTRING(CAST(QCODE AS   VARCHAR), 4, 1) <> '')
      AND (SUBSTRING(CAST(QCODE AS   VARCHAR), 5, 1)  = '') )
      THEN
        (SELECT Description
        FROM PCO_QUALIFICATIONCODE
        WHERE SERVICEID = 1
        AND CODE        = SUBSTRING(CAST(QCODE AS VARCHAR), 1, 3)
        )
      WHEN ((SUBSTRING(CAST(QCODE AS VARCHAR), 1, 3) IS NOT NULL)
      AND (SUBSTRING(CAST(QCODE AS   VARCHAR), 4, 1) <> '')
      AND (SUBSTRING(CAST(QCODE AS   VARCHAR), 5, 1) <> '') )
      THEN
        (SELECT Description
        FROM PCO_QUALIFICATIONCODE
        WHERE SERVICEID = 1
        AND CODE        = SUBSTRING(CAST(QCODE AS VARCHAR), 1, 3)
        )
    END CUSTOMDATA2,
    CASE
      WHEN ((SUBSTRING(CAST(QCODE AS VARCHAR), 1, 3) IS NOT NULL)
      AND (SUBSTRING(CAST(QCODE AS   VARCHAR), 4, 1)  = '')
      AND (SUBSTRING(CAST(QCODE AS   VARCHAR), 5, 1)  = '') )
      THEN
        CASE
          WHEN CUSTOMDATA3 IS NULL
          OR CUSTOMDATA3    = 'NULL'
          THEN ''
          ELSE CUSTOMDATA3
        END
      WHEN ((SUBSTRING(CAST(QCODE AS VARCHAR), 1, 3) IS NOT NULL)
      AND (SUBSTRING(CAST(QCODE AS   VARCHAR), 4, 1) <> '')
      AND (SUBSTRING(CAST(QCODE AS   VARCHAR), 5, 1)  = '') )
      THEN
        (SELECT Description
        FROM PCO_QUALIFICATIONCODE
        WHERE SERVICEID = 1
        AND CODE        = SUBSTRING(CAST(QCODE AS VARCHAR), 1, 4)
        )
      WHEN ((SUBSTRING(CAST(QCODE AS VARCHAR), 1, 3) IS NOT NULL)
      AND (SUBSTRING(CAST(QCODE AS   VARCHAR), 4, 1) <> '')
      AND (SUBSTRING(CAST(QCODE AS   VARCHAR), 5, 1) <> '') )
      THEN
        CASE
          WHEN (SELECT Description
            FROM PCO_QUALIFICATIONCODE
            WHERE SERVICEID = 1
            AND CODE        = SUBSTRING(CAST(QCODE AS VARCHAR), 1, 4)) IS NOT NULL
          THEN
            (SELECT Description
            FROM PCO_QUALIFICATIONCODE
            WHERE SERVICEID = 1
            AND CODE        = SUBSTRING(CAST(QCODE AS VARCHAR), 1, 4)
            ) + ' / ' +
            (SELECT Description
            FROM PCO_QUALIFICATIONCODE
            WHERE SERVICEID = 1
            AND CODE        = SUBSTRING(CAST(QCODE AS VARCHAR), 1, 5)
            )
          ELSE
            (SELECT Description
            FROM PCO_QUALIFICATIONCODE
            WHERE SERVICEID = 1
            AND CODE        = SUBSTRING(CAST(QCODE AS VARCHAR), 1, 5)
            )
        END
      ELSE ''
    END CUSTOMDATA3
  FROM [SQLPR1].[PREP].[PCO_INBOUNDLOG]
  WHERE SERVICEID = 1
  AND QCODE       > 9
  GROUP BY QCODE,
    CUSTOMDATA2,
    CUSTOMDATA3
  ) ActividadesActivas
ON PCO_QUALIFICATIONCODE.CODE = ActividadesActivas.QCODE
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT [QCODE],
    CASE
      WHEN ((SUBSTRING(CAST(QCODE AS VARCHAR), 1, 3) IS NOT NULL)
      AND (SUBSTRING(CAST(QCODE AS   VARCHAR), 4, 1)  = '')
      AND (SUBSTRING(CAST(QCODE AS   VARCHAR), 5, 1)  = '') )
      THEN
        (SELECT Description
        FROM PCO_QUALIFICATIONCODE
        WHERE SERVICEID = 1
        AND CODE        = SUBSTRING(CAST(QCODE AS VARCHAR), 1, 3)
        )
      WHEN ((SUBSTRING(CAST(QCODE AS VARCHAR), 1, 3) IS NOT NULL)
      AND (SUBSTRING(CAST(QCODE AS   VARCHAR), 4, 1) <> '')
      AND (SUBSTRING(CAST(QCODE AS   VARCHAR), 5, 1)  = '') )
      THEN
        (SELECT Description
        FROM PCO_QUALIFICATIONCODE
        WHERE SERVICEID = 1
        AND CODE        = SUBSTRING(CAST(QCODE AS VARCHAR), 1, 3)
        )
      WHEN ((SUBSTRING(CAST(QCODE AS VARCHAR), 1, 3) IS NOT NULL)
      AND (SUBSTRING(CAST(QCODE AS   VARCHAR), 4, 1) <> '')
      AND (SUBSTRING(CAST(QCODE AS   VARCHAR), 5, 1) <> '') )
      THEN
        (SELECT Description
        FROM PCO_QUALIFICATIONCODE
        WHERE SERVICEID = 1
        AND CODE        = SUBSTRING(CAST(QCODE AS VARCHAR), 1, 3)
        )
    END CUSTOMDATA2,
    CASE
      WHEN ((SUBSTRING(CAST(QCODE AS VARCHAR), 1, 3) IS NOT NULL)
      AND (SUBSTRING(CAST(QCODE AS   VARCHAR), 4, 1)  = '')
      AND (SUBSTRING(CAST(QCODE AS   VARCHAR), 5, 1)  = '') )
      THEN
        CASE
          WHEN CUSTOMDATA3 IS NULL
          OR CUSTOMDATA3    = 'NULL'
          THEN ''
          ELSE CUSTOMDATA3
        END
      WHEN ((SUBSTRING(CAST(QCODE AS VARCHAR), 1, 3) IS NOT NULL)
      AND (SUBSTRING(CAST(QCODE AS   VARCHAR), 4, 1) <> '')
      AND (SUBSTRING(CAST(QCODE AS   VARCHAR), 5, 1)  = '') )
      THEN
        (SELECT Description
        FROM PCO_QUALIFICATIONCODE
        WHERE SERVICEID = 1
        AND CODE        = SUBSTRING(CAST(QCODE AS VARCHAR), 1, 4)
        )
      WHEN ((SUBSTRING(CAST(QCODE AS VARCHAR), 1, 3) IS NOT NULL)
      AND (SUBSTRING(CAST(QCODE AS   VARCHAR), 4, 1) <> '')
      AND (SUBSTRING(CAST(QCODE AS   VARCHAR), 5, 1) <> '') )
      THEN
        CASE
          WHEN (SELECT Description
            FROM PCO_QUALIFICATIONCODE
            WHERE SERVICEID = 1
            AND CODE        = SUBSTRING(CAST(QCODE AS VARCHAR), 1, 4)) IS NOT NULL
          THEN
            (SELECT Description
            FROM PCO_QUALIFICATIONCODE
            WHERE SERVICEID = 1
            AND CODE        = SUBSTRING(CAST(QCODE AS VARCHAR), 1, 4)
            ) + ' / ' +
            (SELECT Description
            FROM PCO_QUALIFICATIONCODE
            WHERE SERVICEID = 1
            AND CODE        = SUBSTRING(CAST(QCODE AS VARCHAR), 1, 5)
            )
          ELSE
            (SELECT Description
            FROM PCO_QUALIFICATIONCODE
            WHERE SERVICEID = 1
            AND CODE        = SUBSTRING(CAST(QCODE AS VARCHAR), 1, 5)
            )
        END
      ELSE ''
    END CUSTOMDATA3,
    COUNT(*) TOTAL
  FROM [SQLPR1].[PREP].[PCO_INBOUNDLOG]
  WHERE [SERVICEID] = 1
  AND RDATE BETWEEN '2017/02/01 00:00:00' AND '2018/02/20 23:59:59'
  GROUP BY QCODE,
    CUSTOMDATA2,
    CUSTOMDATA3
  ) Totales
ON ActividadesActivas.QCODE         = Totales.QCODE
AND ActividadesActivas.CUSTOMDATA2  = Totales.CUSTOMDATA2
AND ActividadesActivas.CUSTOMDATA3  = Totales.CUSTOMDATA3
WHERE SERVICEID                     = 1
AND PCO_QUALIFICATIONCODE.CODE NOT IN (102,103,104,105,106,107,113)
GROUP BY PCO_QUALIFICATIONCODE.CODE,
  ActividadesActivas.CUSTOMDATA2,
  ActividadesActivas.CUSTOMDATA3,
  Totales.TOTAL
ORDER BY CAST(PCO_QUALIFICATIONCODE.CODE AS VARCHAR),
  CUSTOMDATA2
```

Comment: That code is completely illegible. SQL should be written as a multi-line language, and indented appropriately. Please format your SQL properly. most likely, the reason for your error will also complete obvious once you do.

Comment: This code is very low quality, and should be completely rewritten. It hurts my eyes

Comment: @t-clausen.dk It's not just my eyes it's hurting. I think it actually made me die a little inside.

Comment: I've approved the suggested edit, as it's a vast improvement. If anyone else can, please do. :)

Comment: Honestly, this is likely going to be impossible for any of us to trouble shoot without DDL. We can't replicate your problem, so all we have to go on is your SQL, and your error; which is that `CUSTOMDATA2` is an invalid column. I'd suggest the error is right though, you're referencing `CUSTOMDATA2` in an object where it doesn't exist.  There's a lot more,however, wrong with that query. There's so many subqueries that it makes it very difficult to understand at all what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is in the group by.

You are masking your field "ActividadesActivas.[CUSTOMDATA2]" with "CUSTOMDATA2"

```
CASE
    WHEN (ActividadesActivas.[CUSTOMDATA2] IS NULL)
    THEN
      (SELECT Description
      FROM PCO_QUALIFICATIONCODE BIS
      WHERE SERVICEID = 1
      AND BIS.CODE    = SUBSTRING(CAST(PCO_QUALIFICATIONCODE.CODE AS VARCHAR), 1, 3)
      )
    ELSE ActividadesActivas.[CUSTOMDATA2]
  END CUSTOMDATA2,
```

so, in the group by, you can only use "CUSTOMDATA2" and not "ActividadesActivas.[CUSTOMDATA2]"

```
GROUP BY PCO_QUALIFICATIONCODE.CODE,
  ActividadesActivas.CUSTOMDATA2,
  ActividadesActivas.CUSTOMDATA3,
  Totales.TOTAL
```

PS: same rule should apply to remaining fields.

EDIT: I'm not sure if that is the only issue with your query, but that is the reason for your issue "Invalid column name 'CUSTOMDATA2'"

Comment: Thanks. It was very difficult whitout ddl. At the last it was stupid change with the names of fields arggg... #!%&  (customdata changed for contactdata )